# nth-child doesn't work in IE7/IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, css, css-selectors

I cannot get the `:nth-child` selector to work with IE7/8.

[Here is](http://www.poipleshadow.com/Goa-Mapusa-Taxi-Price-List.htm) a working example of my code (that works in Chrome)

Below is the CSS and HTML I am using:

**CSS:**

```
#price-list {
    width:98%;
    padding:1%;
    border:white 1px solid;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}        
#price-list h4 {
    padding-top:20px; 
    font-weight:400;  
    padding-bottom:5px;
}        
#price-list ul { 
    width:100%; 
    margin-bottom:10px; 
    overflow:hidden; 
}      
#price-list li{
    line-height:1.5em;
    border-bottom:1px  dashed #C9F;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    padding-top:5px; 
    padding-bottom:5px;
    text-align:center;          
}        
#price-list li strong { 
    color:#C9F; 
    font-weight:normal;
}        
#double-taxi li:nth-child(odd) { 
    width:80%;
    text-align:left; 
}
#double-taxi li:nth-child(even) { 
    width:20%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="price-list">
   <ul id="double-taxi">            
      <li><h4>North Goa</h4><strong>(Distance kms)</strong></li><li><h4>Non A/C</h4>Rs <strong>(UK &pound;)</strong></li>
      <li>Aldona <strong>(10 kms)</strong></li><li>250 Rs <strong> (&pound;3)</strong></li>
      <li>Asnora <strong>(15 kms)</strong></li><li>250 Rs <strong> (&pound;3)</strong></li>
      <li>Bicholim <strong>(21 kms)</strong></li><li>420 Rs <strong> (&pound;5)</strong></li>
      <li>Camurlim <strong>(10 kms)</strong></li><li>250 Rs <strong> (&pound;3)</strong></li>
      <li>Colvale <strong>(10 kms)</strong></li><li>250 Rs <strong> (&pound;3)</strong></li>
   </ul>
     We DO NOT provide a taxi service. The Exchange Rate used to calculate UKP was 80Rs to the UKP and was rounded  up to whole pound.
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong -- IE7 and IE8 don't support that.  You'll need to use JS to accommodate it, or accept that older browser versions will look less flashy than newer browser versions.

Comment: You can use [JQuery's nth-child() selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/).

Comment: it's a CSS3 rule that is not supported pre-IE9

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because `:nth-child` [**isn't supported in IE7/IE8**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child).

One solution to this problem would be to use  [**Selectivizr**](http://selectivizr.com/).

> "Selectivizr is a JavaScript utility that emulates CSS3 pseudo-classes
>   and attribute selectors in Internet Explorer 6-8."

All you need to do is include the Selectivizr script and, if you aren't already using one, decide which JavaScript library you'd like to use (jQuery, Mootools etc.) and you will have support for the `:nth-child` selector (amongst various other pseudo-selectors/attribute selectors) in IE6 through to IE8.

**Edit:**

In reply to your comment, [**here's a quick tutorial**](http://blog.reybango.com/2010/09/08/start-using-css3-pseudo-classes-in-internet-explorer-6-7-and-8-using-the-selectivizr-javascript-library/) showing you how to set up and use Selectivizr.

Comment: and also a javascript plugin like jQuery or motools is must.

Comment: @Mr_Green Yep, there's a table showing which selectors are supported in each of the major libraries on the website. Pretty useful utility if you ask me :)

Comment: You need to use Selectivizr and jquery to get it to work?  Please could you put the code required as an example as I have always kept away from Javascript where ever possible

Comment: @user2443301 Here's a quick tutorial, should only take you a couple of minutes :) - http://blog.reybango.com/2010/09/08/start-using-css3-pseudo-classes-in-internet-explorer-6-7-and-8-using-the-selectivizr-javascript-library/

Comment: Can I put the Jquery line inside the if statement so I only load it for IE as I don't use it otherwise....


<!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
  <script src="jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="selectivizr.js"></script>
  <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="Charity.css" /></noscript>
<![endif]-->

Comment: @user2443301 I'd imagine so yes :) Please remember to upvote/accept my answer if it helped you, thanks man!

Comment: Can you check the source to see if all is correct? - 

[link](http://www.poipleshadow.com/Goa-Mapusa-Taxi-Price-List.htm)

Doesn't seem to be working... ?

Comment: @user2443301 Have you followed the tutorial completely? If you have, it will work. Which element are you using first-child on? I can see that selectivizr is succesfully loading in IE8

Comment: I am using nth child (it creates the table like structure listing the taxi prices)

#double-taxi li:nth-child(odd) { width:80%; text-align:left; }
#double-taxi li:nth-child(even) { width:20%;

Comment: @user2443301 Are you still there? Please remember to accept/upvote my answer once you have fixed the html/css :) thanks man.

Answer (score 7):

> **Below example may be helpful for you**

```
//For first child
// equivalent to li:nth-child(1)
li:first-child a {
    border-top: 5px solid red;
}

//For second child
// equivalent to li:nth-child(2)
li:first-child + li a {
    border-top: 5px solid blue;
}

//For third child
// equivalent to li:nth-child(3)
 li:first-child + li + li a {
    border-top: 5px solid green;
}​
```

Comment: could you add some explanation of the css you've provided?

Comment: it's worth knowing about, but it doesn't solve cases such as `nth-child(odd)` from the question. Also `first-child` and `+` selectors have severe bugs in IE7, so aren't really that good as an alternative solution.

Comment: [***More Details***](http://www.thebrightlines.com/2010/01/04/alternative-for-nth-of-type-and-nth-child/)

Comment: Also, for reference [CSS Sibling Selectors](https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

Use a polyfill such as selectivizer for the missing functionality.

1. Download it from selectivizr.com at http://selectivizr.com/downloads/selectivizr-1.0.2.zip
2. Unzip it and put the file in in your project under app/assets/javascripts
3. Reference it in your app for ie only with `<!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]><script type="text/javascript" src="selectivizr-min.js"></script><![endif]-->` in your layout's application.js file. or...
4. For the asset pipeline you can add gem 'selectivizr-rails' to our Gemfile and then bundle install. You get the gem from https://github.com/jhubert/selectivizr-rails

   Then add the following to the head tag in your layout:

   `<!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
   = javascript_include_tag 'selectivizr'
   <![endif]-->`
5. proceed as normal