# Continuous nth-child (multiple occurrences)

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a list made of thousands of items.

In order to display them in a clean fashion, I need to apply a specific css rule to every third item of the list (3th li, 6th li, 9th li,....,3000th li..9999th li...).

Normally, I would use this:

```
li:nth-child(3),li:nth-child(6),...
```

but this would obviously be too tedious to write a css rule for each item (not to mention that the list may grow over time)

I also may use a class for every third item of the list but the list is reordered constantly according to a filter by a jQuery plugin (Quicksand), so the 6th li can asynchronously become the 4th one according to the user manipulation.

So, is there a way to use a css rule that would simply do something like this?:

```
li:nth-child(n*3)
```

Thank you.

Comment: since Hashem gave the answer, so there is no room for another answer.. just made a demo link. http://jsbin.com/qabofewo/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`:nth-child(an+b)`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) pseudo class as `li:nth-child(3n+3)` in order to select **every third** list item (`a` parameter) starting from **3rd** `<li>` element (`b` parameter).

In which:

```
n starts from 0

n = 0: (3 * 0 + 3) = 3 => 3rd element
n = 1: (3 * 1 + 3) = 6 => 6th element
n = 2: (3 * 2 + 3) = 9 => 9th element
...
```

```css
li:nth-child(3n+3) {
    background-color: gold;
}
```

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/V3FFf/)**. *(Which is the same as [`li:nth-child(3n)`](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/V3FFf/1/))*.

From the **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child)**:

> The `:nth-child(an+b)` CSS pseudo-class matches an element that has
>   an+b-1 siblings before it in the document tree, for a given positive
>   or zero value for n, and has a parent element.

It's worth noting that `:nth-child` pseudo-class [is supported in **IE9+**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: just curious is there any drawback if used `nth-of-type` in this example.. I choose `nth-of-type` to select every 3rd element. the demo is here. http://jsbin.com/qabofewo/2

Comment: @KheemaPandey Since the only valid child of list elements is `<li>`, `nth-of-type` behaves as the same as `:nth-child`.

Comment: I didn't know that "+1" thing but it makes sense.Thank you

Comment: so you mean if any other HTML element added inside li then it won't work?

Comment: @KheemaPandey By *list elements* I meant `<ul>`/`<ol>` elements, not the list items `<li>`.

Comment: Oops! I accepted the answer but didn't see that this solution is not supported by IE8. Is there a workaround for IE8 then?

Comment: @Baylock For the [limited amount of elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492121/ie8-nth-child-and-before) you could use adjacent sibling selectors, but it's not possible to emulate such a `:nth-child(3n+3)` selector for unlimited elements. However, you might want to consider using [Selectivizr](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16873425/1725764) to get `nth-child` to work on **IE6-8**

Comment: @Baylock You could also use **[IE7.js](https://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/)** JavaScript library. Check the [demo](http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/test/nth-child.html).

Comment: I'll go and have a look at both selectivizr and IE7.js, thank you. Any script is fine as long as it works on ie8 eventually (I decided not to support IE6 and IE7 anymore).