# jQuery: find TDs containing x by column instead of by row

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, each

I am using the following lines to search through the rows of a table to check if a TD contains my searchTerm which works fine so far.

Is there a way that instead of searching by row I can search by column here ? 
The reason why is that in my case a row can contain the same value multiple times but not a column which is what I need here.

My table has a standard structure with thead and tbody and I can add a colgroup or classes if needed.

**My JS:**

```
var searchTerm = "myText"
var result = new Array();
$('#myTable tbody tr').each(function() {
    result.push(+($(this).find('td:contains(' + searchTerm + ')').next('td').text()));
});
alert(result);
```

**My table:**

```
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="myHeader">Cat 1</th>
            <th>Vol 1</th>
            <th class="myHeader">Cat 2</th>
            <th>Vol 2</th>
            <th class="myHeader">Cat 3</th>
            <th>Vol 3</th>
            //...
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>item1</td><td>8</td><td>item2</td><td>7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>item3</td><td>5</td><td>item2</td><td>7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>item2</td><td>1</td><td>item1</td><td>5</td><td>item3</td><td>3</td>
        </tr>
        //...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Many thanks in advance, Tim.

Comment: Use `jQuery.index()`.

Comment: Thanks. How would I apply this here so that it searches through all columns ? (My table has a fixed set of 13 columns.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop on you columns and read each cell using [`nth:child`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector:

> Selects all elements that are the nth-child of their parent.

Code:

```
var searchTerm = "myText"
var result = new Array();
for (var index = 0; index < $('#myTable thead th').length; index++) {
    $('#myTable tbody td:nth-child(' + index + ')').each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':contains(' + searchTerm + ')'))
        result.push(+($(this).next('td').text()));
    });
}
alert(result);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/6Et6F/

Comment: Thanks a lot - this looks great. Am I right that this is not supported in IE8 and if, is there a workaround to make this work in both IE8 and IE9 ? Can I use eq() instead to cover this ?

Comment: I have to check it, to alternatively you can use selectivzr http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873391/nth-child-doesnt-work-in-ie7-ie8

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#myTable tbody tr:nth-child(myNumber)').each(function() {
  var tdInMyNumberColumnValue = $(this).val();
 //do stuff
}
```

use `nth-child(myNumber)` (ex: `nth-child(6)`) to check just the td in column you want. In example, column 6.

Of course, you can assign a class just the `<td>` you want inspect and use an each related to this class selector.