# How can i reshape to 2-column at internet explorer 7

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a table like this and i want this;

[image]

```css
    tr {
    float: left !important;
}

tr:nth-child(2n+1) {
    clear: left !important;
  padding-right: 10px !important;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
       
           <tr><td>1</td></tr> 
           <tr><td>2</td></tr> 
           <tr><td>3</td></tr> 
           <tr><td>4</td></tr> 
           <tr><td>5</td></tr> 
           <tr><td>6</td></tr> 
           <tr><td>7</td></tr> 
           <tr><td>8</td></tr> 
           <tr><td>9</td></tr> 
 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This code not working internet explorer 7, how can i solve? This is explorer 7 result;
[image]

Comment: IE7, really? ...

Comment: Try this: [nth-child doesn't work in IE7/IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873391/nth-child-doesnt-work-in-ie7-ie8)
But do you really need IE7 support?

Comment: yes my firends, i really need ie7 support :(

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
table, tbody, tr {
    display: block;
}

tr {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying to use DIV instead of a table. It may help you to achieve the desired output for the IE 7 browser.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #container, #left, #right{margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;}
    #left{width: 10%; float: left;}
    #right{width: 90%; float: right;}
    </style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="left">
1
</div>
<div id="right">
2
</div>
  <div id="left">
3
</div>
<div id="right">
4
</div>
</div>
<div id="left">
5
</div>
<div id="right">
6
</div>
</div>
<div id="left">
7
</div>
<div id="right">
8
</div>
<div id="right">
9
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Output in the IE 11 browser with Document mode IE 7:

[image]